# Aligning (Scaled?) Greek Letters

Tags: vertical-alignment, greek

Is there a good way to align letters that fall below the line of text? In the below I was hoping to have the bottom of the 'x' and the chi to be aligned.

```
\usepackage[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
x\scalebox{1.5}{$\chi$}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this may not be a good idea.  if you have a capital "X" in a script or calligraphic font, for example, it might be confused.  would you raise a latin "g" so that there's nothing below the baseline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You first need to know whether the bounding box of the content sets at the bottom end of object. To do this, you can use a (coloured) `\framebox`:

[image]

The above shows that this is the case - the bottom-end of the bounding box sits at the bottom-end of the symbol/object. The bottom-end is below the baseline and therefore has a depth associated with it. Using `\raisebox` you can lift it by `\depth` - the natural depth of the object:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\newcommand{\showbb}[1]{{% \showbb{<stuff>} to show the bounding box
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{-.5\fboxrule}% Adjust framed box gap
  \fcolorbox{red!30}{white}{#1}}}% Set box
\begin{document}
\showbb{x}\showbb{\scalebox{1.5}{$\chi$}}

x\raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{1.5}{$\chi$}}
\end{document}
```